# Filling a region in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

What are my options to shade the region like below:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (12, 6);
\draw (3,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (0, 0)--(12,6);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0)--(12,6)--(12,0)--cycle; 
  \clip (3,0) rectangle (12,6);
  \fill[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (12,6) (3,3) circle[radius=3cm] (9,3) circle[radius=3cm];
\end{scope}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (12, 6);
\draw (3,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (0, 0)--(12,6);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not the most elegant solution as you have to adjust your clipping area, when moving the circles around, but I'm sure this could be refined (e.g. using the calc library).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (12, 6);
        \draw (3,3) circle [radius=3cm];
        \draw (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
        \draw (0, 0)--(12,6);
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
            % you have to adjust the following line when moving your circles around
            \clip  (3,0)    % bottom of first circle
                -- (6,3)    % intersection of circles
                -- (12,6)   % upper right corner
                -- (12,0)   % lower right corner
                -- cycle;
            \fill (3,3) circle [radius=3cm] (0, 0) -- (12,6) -- (12, 0) -- cycle (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: here's the preview]

Answer (score 4):

very close:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (12,6);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) -- (12,6) -| cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (3,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw[fill=white] (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (0, 0)--(12,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

more close:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (12,6);
\fill[white] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) -- (12,6) -| cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (3,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw[fill=white] (9,3) circle [radius=3cm];
\draw (0, 0)--(12,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This only works as long as there is nothing in the unshaded regions that is covered here...